# What is the position of my keyframe animated object?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm an experienced developer but completely inexperienced with 3d modeling and python.

I have a modeled a Rubik's cube containing 26 (center omitted) cubes where the center cube, if I had one, would be at 0,0,0. When I rotate a face with keyframe animation, all of those 6 cubes report a location of 0,0,0. I think that is because it is reporting their pivot which I have set to the 3d cursor at 0,0,0.

`somecube.matrix_local` appears to be interesting but the documentation does not say what the return values actually represent and I cannot see the pattern I would expect on the results of adjacent cubes.

All I want to know is how I can find cubes by name on a certain "face" of the Rubik's cube. So all cubes on x = 0 or all cubes on x = 1 or all cubes on x = -1 and likewise for y and z. Or more generally, *how do I get the center coordinates of an object that has been animated by keyframes?*

If the object has not been animated, the `location` is obvious but I'm lost once I rotate anything around 0,0,0 which is where I set the 3d cursor.

for reference, cubes (each size of 2) that I would expect to be at (2,2,2) , (2,0,2) and (2,-2,2) show:

```
>>> ob1.matrix_local
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))

>>> ob7.matrix_local
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -2.000000238418579),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.999999761581421),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))

>>> ob4.matrix_local
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

Comment: HI.  The pivot point setting has no influence on the object matrices.   Are there any constraints or parenting involved? Are you keyframing location?  FWIW I would set up to  only keyframe rotation. The locations are set by the size of the cube. Each mini cube is one of  three types, corner, face centre, edge centre.  Make all 3 positive quadrant cubes  with origins at (0, 0, 0) (or positioned and parented to empty at (0,0, 0) etc.) Others are a mirror copy across the three axes. (akin to 90 degree rotation steps)

Comment: @batFINGER there is no parenting and I don't think there are any constraints (I'm not even sure what that is). Only rotation is keyframed, not location. The Google has failed me in figuring out what the 16 floats returned from `matrix_local` represent. Should I even be looking at that?